# Pytorch built in dataset loading

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, dataset, torchvision

I would appreciate if anyone could offer me a solution or a suggestion on how to fix ther error I'm facing when loading the builtin FashionMNIST dataset (I'm using WSL Ubuntu with cuda enabled)

```
from torchvision import datasets
train_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root='data',
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor(),
    target_transform=None
)

test_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
    root='data',
    train=False,
    download=True,
    transform=ToTensor(),
    target_transform=None
)
```

error I'm getting

```
Downloading http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Downloading http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz to data/FashionMNIST/raw/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
  0%|          | 0/26421880 [00:00<?, ?it/s]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 3
      1 ## setup trainin data
      2 from torchvision import datasets
----> 3 train_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
      4     root='data',
      5     train=True,
      6     download=True,
      7     transform=ToTensor(),
      8     target_transform=None
      9 )
     11 test_data = datasets.FashionMNIST(
     12     root='data',
     13     train=False,
   (...)
     16     target_transform=None
     17 )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py:99, in MNIST.__init__(self, root, train, transform, target_transform, download)
     96     return
     98 if download:
---> 99     self.download()
    101 if not self._check_exists():
    102     raise RuntimeError("Dataset not found. You can use download=True to download it")
...
     37         for chunk in content:
     38             # filter out keep-alive new chunks
     39             if not chunk:

AttributeError: __enter__
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

I would appreciate any help

So far I have tried to remove the data folder and then setup another folder which still fails. But i can download the dataset using wget.

Comment: what do you mean you tried "removing the data folder and then setting up another folder... but can download the dataset..." ? I'm running python 3.10.12 and I am able to load the data without an issue.

Comment: i can't donwload the pytorch dataset using the 'torchvision' 'import satasets' I could download it intially but then after that it ran into an error when i ran the file again. So i removed the 'data' folder and tried to run the code again the issue is persistent. Then I remove the entire dataset and manully downloaded the dataset using 'wget http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz' and set the 'download=False'. After that i was able to run the code without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to bypass the error.
firstly I removed the previously downloaded FashionMnist dataset.
Then I downloaded the training and testing datasets manually using

`wget http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz`
`wget http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz`
`wget http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz`
 `wget http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz`

then set the correct file path in the `root='data'` as per [FASHIONMNIST](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST.html) then set `download=False`.

above steps were able to bypass the issue.